# Dynamic drop-down list not showing strings

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to make a dynamic drop-down list from a PostgreSQL-query. Basically, the script asks my database what courses (school courses) exists, and then creates a drop-down list of all the courses available.

It connects to the database and retrieves the right values (I've confirmed this myself), but they show up as empty strings when I open the drop-down list. What's even wierder is that if the database contain two courses, there will be two empty fields to choose from in the drop-down list, and if there are three then the list also has three empty fields to choose from.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
The user interface for <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>

<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=*** dbname=*** user=*** password=***")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

// Query for Course Information (for the drop-down box)
$query = 'SELECT * FROM courseinformation';
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Initialize the drop-down list (html-code)
echo "<p>Drop-down list:</p><br>";
echo "<select name=\"formCourse\">";
echo "    <option value=\"\">Select Course</option>";

// Create the items in the drop-down list
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value=\"foo\">$line[0]</option>";
}

// End the drop-down list
echo "</select>";
echo "</p>";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's a picture of what it looks like:
[image: What it looks like]

Asking for `$line` instead of `$line[0]` gives this result:
[image]

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching the results by passing the PGSQL_ASSOC flag. This means your results won't be numerically indexed, such as $line[0] but they will be an associative array with an array key that matches your postgres column heading. So maybe $line['courseTitle'].

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to compile now at all (the website displays a blank screen). What flag can I use to make the columns indexed?
Edit: Nevermind, found it! It was PGSQL_NUM, and now I can use the indexes. Thanks!

Comment: change the line to be while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result)) { as everything except the resource are optional anyway